# Perl and ffmpeg script

Tags: perl, ffmpeg

The first part of my script that asks whether to check for cinavia doesn't work. That is, if I type in 'y' or 'Y' it doesn't  proceed to the `CNVIACHk` function but goes instead to the `MVIEPARAMs` function.

```
# GET FILE INPUT..

print "Enter Filename..";
my $MOVIe = <STDIN>;

print "Check For Cinavia? Enter y or n\n";
my $CNVIAQUESt = <STDIN>;

if ( $CNVIAQUESt eq "y" || $CNVIAQUESt eq "Y" ) {
    CNVIACHk( $MOVIe );
}
else {
    MVIEPARAMs( $MOVIe );
}


sub MVIEPARAMs {

    system(
        "ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $MOVIe"
    );

    print "Duration In Seconds..";
    $DURATIOn = <STDIN>;

    system(
        'ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width "$MOVIe"'
    );

    print "Movie Width? ";
    $MOVIEWIDTh = <STDIN>;

    print "Movie Height? ";
    $MOVIEHEIGHt = <STDIN>;

    print "Enter Target Width.. ";
    $TARGETWIDTh = <STDIN>;

    print "Enter Target Height.. ";
    $TARGETHEIGHt = <STDIN>;

    system(
        'ffprobe -show_entries stream=index,codec_type:stream_tags=language -of compact "$MOVIe" -v 0 | grep eng'
    );

    print "Enter number of English Audio Track.. ";
    $ENGAUDTRk = <STDIN>;

    print "English Audio Track Number Is ", $ENGAUDTRk, ".";
    $BTRTe = 31875072 / $DURATIOn;

    DETRMNEPAd;
}


sub DETRMNEPAd {

    if ( $MOVIEWIDTh < $TARGETWIDTh ) {
        $X = $TARGETWIDTh - $MOVIEWIDTh / 2;
    }
    elsif ( $MOVIEHEIGHt < $TARGETHEIGHt ) {
        $Y = $TARGETHEIGHt - $MOVIEHEIGHt / 2;
        $X = 0;
        print $Y;
    }
    else {
        print "Padding Not Needed Moving On...";
        CNVRTWOPAd();
    }

    CNVRTWPAd();
}


sub CNVIACHk {

    print "Checking Movie For Cinavia.. ";
    system( "cinde -i $MOVIe -q high -l" );

    print "Enter Track To Check.. ";
    $TRKTOCHEk = <STDIN>;

    system( "cinde -i $MOVIe -q high -t $TRKTOCHEk" );

    print "Was Cinavia Detected?";
    $CNVIACHKANSr = <STDIN>;

    if ( $CNVIACHKANSr eq "y" ) {
        exit;
    }
    else {

        print "Would You Like To Check Another Track?";
        $CHKANTHRTRk = <STDIN>;

        if ( $CHKANTHRTRk eq "y" ) {
            CNVIACHk();
        }
        else {
            MVIEPARAMs();
        }
    }
}


sub CNVRTWOPAd {

    print "BEGINNING CONVERSION...\n";

    print "What Preset Would You Like To Use?";
    $PRESEt = <STDIN>;

    system(
        "ffmpeg -i $MOVIe -map 0:0 -map 0:$ENGAUDTRk -c:v libx264 -b:v $BTRTe -preset $PRESEt -strict -2 -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k -threads 12 -pass 1 -f matroska dummy && ",
        "ffmpeg -i $MOVIe -map 0:0 -map 0:$ENGAUDTRk -c:v libx264 -b:v $BTRTe -preset $PRESEt -strict -2 -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k -threads 12 -pass 2 -f matroska ENCODE1.mkv"
    );
}


sub CNVRTWPAd {

    print "BEGINNING CONVERSION...\n";

    print "What Preset Would You Like To Use?";
    my $PRESEt = <STDIN>;

    system(
        "ffmpeg -i $MOVIe -map 0:0 -map 0:$ENGAUDTRk -c:v libx264 -b:v $BTRTe -preset $PRESEt -vf \"pad=$TARGETWIDTh:$TARGETHEIGHt:$X:$Y:black\" -strict -2 -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k ",
        " -threads 12 -pass 1 -f matroska dummy && ffmpeg -i $MOVIe -map 0:0 -map 0:$ENDAUDTRk -c:v libx264 -b:v $BTRTe -preset $PRESEt -vf \"pad=$TARGETWIDTh:$TARGETHEIGHt:$X:$Y:black\"",
        " -strict -2 -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k -threads 12 -pass 2 -f matroska ENCODE1.mkv"
    );
}
```

Comment: That's a strange method to name your VARIABLEs.

Comment: yeah i like allcaps but wasn't sure if it was safe..

Comment: You should follow the guidelines for the programming language you are using. In general, Perl lexical variables use lower-case letters and `snake_case`, globals are in upper case, and modules and package names have capital initials `Like::This`. Take a look at [`perldoc perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html)
You must also `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, and declare all your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use.

Comment: It is essential to use white space to lay out your program so that it is readable and its structure is clear. I have edited your question to do this for you; hopefully you agree that it is clearer this way. It's also worth saying that you have written far too much code before you tried to test it. You should ordinarily write no more than about three of four lines before you run what you have written and make sure that party works before you build on it. Also note that `system` can take only a single command: you can't pass a list of commands like that.

Comment: It's `chomp()`. It's pretty much always `chomp()` :-)

Comment: thanks Borondin that's nicely done--a whole lot better layout than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

```
my $CNVIAQUESt=<STDIN>;
if($CNVIAQUESt eq "y" || $CNVIAQUESt eq "Y") {
```

After pressing `y` or `Y`, you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That's part of the input, so `$CNVIAQUESt eq "y\n"` in fact. To remove the newline from the value, use

```
chomp $CNVIAQUESt;
```

after reading the input. See [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) for details.

Comment: and that is something you should do for all your other variables after reading from <STDIN>